# Illegal character in property name when serializing JSON to dynamic

Tags: c#, dynamic, json.net

I am trying to deserialize JSON that contains dash (-) characters in some of its property names, by using dynamic types:

```
string json = MyWebClient.DownloadString("http://api.crossref.org/works/10.1093/brain/75.2.187");
dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
string title = result.message.title[0];
string journal = result.message.container-title[0];
```

I cannot get the "container-title" value due to use of an illegal character. And I don't want to simply use `Replace()` to remove dash characters. Is there any way?

Answer (score 2):

Since `message` is also a `JObject` you can access its properties like a dictionary

```
result.message["container-title"]
```