# Deserialize JSON with $ in property names

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the following  JSON object (the shape of the object will vary hence use of dynamic):

```
{
    "mba$maccType": [{
        "class": {
            "id": 1057,
            "intlId": "cacc"
        },
        "classA": false,
        "endDate": "4712-12-31T00:00:00",
        "histStatus": {
            "id": 5,
            "intlId": "valid"
        },
        "objClassif": {
            "id": 74,
            "intlId": "mba$macc_type"
        },
        "secUser": {
            "id": 2
        },
        "startDate": "2018-12-01T00:00:00",
        "timestamp": "2020-01-18T07:29:21"
    }
]
}
```

I'm using Newtonsoft.Json to parse as follows:

```
dynamic dyn = JObject.Parse(json);
```

My problem is, I'm unable to reference any dynamic properties because the parent property containing the $ gives a syntax error:

```
Console.WriteLine(dyn.mba$maccType);
```

How can I get to the value of "class.intlId" (i.e. "cacc")?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When there are illegal characters in properties names after dynamic-deserializing of a JSON in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36726153/when-there-are-illegal-characters-in-properties-names-after-dynamic-deserializin)

Comment: The linked question uses `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>`, but it leads to the same `JObject` with illegal characters in the property names, so the answer should also apply in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse your JSON to [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) instead of `dynamic` type and access its items by key. Like get the first item from `mba$maccType` (since it's an array), then access a `class` token and `intlId` value from it

```cs
var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
var firstItem = jObject["mba$maccType"]?.FirstOrDefault();
var result = firstItem?["class"]?["intlId"]?.ToString(); // returns "cacc"
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that the only dynamic part of your JSON structure are the property names on the outer object, you can deserialize this JSON to a `Dictionary<string, List<T>>`. The benefit of doing this is that you would have clearly defined types for almost everything that's deserialized.

```
// type definitions
class ClassRecord
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string intlId { get; set; }
}

class Item
{
    public ClassRecord @class { get; set; }
    public bool classA { get; set; }

    // etc.
}

// deserialize
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<Item>>>(json);

Console.WriteLine(obj["mba$maccType"][0].@class.id); // 1057
```